# Vue3 equivalent of vNode.computedInstance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm in the process of converting my app from Vue2 to Vue3, but have gotten stalled out on one aspect of my forms.

I'm using SFCs for form element components (FormInput, FormTextArea, FormCheckbox, etc.), and passing them into form container components (FormGroup, FormTab, etc) using slots, like so:

```
<ssi-form>
  <ssi-form-tabs>
    <ssi-form-tab title="tab1">
      <ssi-form-input title="name" ... />
      <ssi-form-checkbox title="active" ... />
    </ssi-form-tab>
  </ssi-form-tabs>
</ssi-form>
```

Those parent containers need to view some computed properties of the child form elements to pull error messages to the top.

In Vue2, I used the mounted lifecycle hook (with the options API) to read the slots and access the computed properties, like this:

```
  mounted: function() {
    const vm = this;

    this.$slots.default.forEach((vNode) => {
      const vueComponent = vNode.componentInstance;
      vueComponent.$on("invalid", vm.onInvalid);

      if (vueComponent.errorCount === undefined) return;
      this.childFormElements.push(vueComponent);
    });
  },
```

Using this setup, I could grab the `errorCount` computed property from each child in the slot, so I could aggregate errors going up to the top level of the form.

Now that I'm switching to Vue3, it seems like `componentInstance` doesn't exist. I tried setting up similar logic using the `onMounted` directive, but when I access the slot elements, I can't find any way to see their `errorCount` computed property:

```
onMounted(() => { 
  slots.default().forEach((vNode) => {
    console.log(vNode);
  });
});
```

The logged object does not contain the computed property. I thought I found something useful when I read about `defineExpose`, but even after exposing the `errorCount` property, nothing comes up.

Here is the `<script setup>` from the SFC for the text input that I'm trying to work with:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, defineProps, defineEmits, computed } from "vue";

let props = defineProps<{
  label: string, 
  id: string, 
  modelValue: string|number, 
  type?: string, 
  description?: string, 
  min?: string|number, 
  max?: string|number, 
  pattern?: string, 
  message?: string
}>();
let emit = defineEmits(["input", "update:modelValue", "invalid"]);

let state = ref(null);
let error = ref("");

const input = ref(null);

function onInput(event: Event) {
  validate();
  emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
}

// methods
function validate() {
  let inputText = input.value;
  if (inputText === null) return;

  inputText.checkValidity();
  state.value = inputText.validity.valid;
  error.value = inputText.validationMessage;
}

const errorCount = computed(() => {
  return state.value === false ? 1 : 0;
});

defineExpose({errorCount})

</script>
```

So the question is - how can a parent component read the `errorCount` property from a component placed into a slot?

Comment: I found out that I can access `errorCount` if I have an explicit `ref` defined for the component. Looking into how to extract refs from slot components, I found another Vue related question that I now think is related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425980/how-get-ref-from-slot-in-vue-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internal properties shouldn't be used without a good reason, especially because they don't belong to public API and can change their behaviour or be removed without notice. A preferable solution is the one that can achieve the goal by means of public API.

Here the solution is to [process slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#rendering-slots) in container component's render function. Vnode objects are the templates for rendered elements and they can be transformed at this point, e.g. a ref from the scope of container component can be added.

If the instances of child components need to be accessed to add event listeners, they [can be added](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#v-on) to a vnode at this point:

```
() => {
  const tabChildren = slots.default?.() || [];
  
  for (childVnode of tabChildren) {
    // Specifically check against a list of components that need special treatment
    if (childVnode.type === SsiFormInputComponent) {
      childVnode.props = {
        ...childVnode.props,
        ref: setTabChildRef,
        onInvalid: invalidHandler,
      };
    }
  }

  return tabChildren;
}
```

Where `setTabChildRef` is [ref function](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs) that maintains a collection of children refs, although it's not needed for the sole purpose of adding event listeners.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but how do I set up the container component's render function? I'm using the "script setup" style, but don't know how to take the code you've put here and get it to run from that script block.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918363/how-to-use-render-function-in-script-setup-vue3 suggests that function component can be dynamically declared and used in a template, which is less efficient by design. A switch to `script` can be made for any edge case that `script setup` can't handle

Comment: Okay, thanks! I still haven't fully figured out how to make this work for me, but I'm going to accept it and award the bounty because I think this puts me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not doable, since it has already been considered a *bad practice* [since Vue 2](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7661#issuecomment-366464392).

`defineExpose` does help in such a situation, but since you said

> I could grab the `errorCount` computed property from each child in the slot

maybe [Provide / Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#provide-inject) could be a better approach?

Comment: Provide / Inject looks really useful, but it doesn't solve my current problem. I don't want to pass data from the root all the way to child nodes. I want to pass data up from a child to it's parent, when the child was provided to the parent in a slot.

Comment: @kingcoyote `provide` works for arbitrary hierarchy of objects, not necessarily from root. It's possible to pass reactive object from a (grand)parent and modify it in a (grand) child, or pass callback functions through it, or event bus instance (could be a replacement for $on). Not a very good pattern because it makes things more convoluted and hard to debug, but when it's needed, it's needed. Isn't really needed here.