# Vue 3 - How can a "container" component know about its "children"?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to create a "container" component, which manages state and reponds to events from its children, something like this:

```
<MyChipGroup v-model="selections">
  <MyChip>Chip 1</MyChip>
  <MyChip>Chip 2</MyChip>
  <MyChip>Chip 3</MyChip>
</MyChipGroup>
```

In Vue 3, the `$children` property has been removed.  Parent components are no longer supposed to have any special knowledge of their children (except perhaps through the use of [`scoped slots`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots).

Before you say this can't be done, Vuetify does exactly the same thing: [VChipGroup](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-chip-group/)

```
<v-chip-group>
  <v-chip>Chip 1</v-chip>
  <v-chip>Chip 2</v-chip>
  <v-chip>Chip 3</v-chip>
</v-chip-group>
```

A read of the API shows that the v-chip-group is able to interact with the v-chips.

How exactly would something like this be implemented in Vue 3?

Possible ideas:

1. Hidden global storage where each child is secretly stashed before mounting (just in case it is needed by a parent container)
2. Some weird DOM element search within the container to back out the child components
3. ???

Comment: This is done in render function by iterating over slot children. You can add onSomeEvent prop to every child vnode. This is lowlevel but acceptable approach. This makes sense for strict slot hierarchy like shown above. For looser one nested comps can interact with a parent through provide/inject

Comment: @EstusFlask can you amplify with an example and add it as an answer?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/72422082/3731501 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000029/3731501  look similar to your case . You can mark your question as a dupe if this solves the problem. Consider updating with the current attempt if you have a problem with this approach

Comment: Thanks! (though it wasn't my case) -- But I voted to do so!  Surprised this isn't discussed more explicitly in the Vue docs.

Comment: Added another link, it looks closer