# _ctx.function is not defined in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, pinia

```
....
</v-container>
  <v-container v-else>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-title v-if="userDetails.name">{{ userDetails.name.givenName + ' ' + userDetails.name.familyName }}</v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
.....
import {mapActions, mapState} from 'pinia';
import {userStatus} from '@/plugins/userHelper';
import Assigner from '@/components/Assigner';
import { useUserStore } from '../../stores/useUserStore';
import { useGroupStore } from '../../stores/useGroupStore';
import { useIndexStore } from '../../stores/useIndexStore';

    export default {
      name: 'UserDetails',
      components: { Assigner },
      data: () => ({
      //
      }),
      computed: {
        ...mapState(useIndexStore,[
        'isLoading'
       ]),
        ...mapState(useUserStore, [
          'userById',
          'userDetails'
       ]),
        ...mapState(useGroupStore, [
          'groups'
       ]),
      },
      user: {
      get() {
        console.log("Details" + this.userDetails);
        return this.userDetails;
      },
      set(updatedUser) {
        this.modifyUser(updatedUser);
      }
    },
....
   methods: {
    ...mapActions(useUserStore, [
      'getUserDetails',
      'saveUser',
      'modifyUser'
    ]),
    ...mapActions(useIndexStore, [
      'saveChanges',
      'setStatusDialog'
    ]), ....
    methods:{
      async beforeMount() {
      console.log("beforeMount"+this.$route.params.id)
      await this.getUserDetails(this.$route.params.id);
      },
     ....
    }
```

```js
    useUserStore
    export const useUserStore = defineStore("UserStore", {

    state: () => {
        return {
          users: [],
          userDetails: {},
          createUser: {},
        }
    },
        actions: {
          async getUsers() {
            await axiosInstance().get('api/admin/users')
            .then((response) => {
              this.users = response.data.users;
              console.log(this.users);
              });
        },
          async getUserDetails(userId) {
            await axiosInstance().get(`api/admin/user/${userId}`)
            .then((response) => {
           // commit('setUserDetails', response.data ? response.data : `error receiving data ${response.status}`);
          this.userDetails = response.data ? response.data : `error receiving data:          ${response.status}`;
          console.log("Details: " + JSON.stringify(this.userDetails));
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.userDetails.name))
        });
     
    },....
```

Hello dear people,

recently i had to switch from vuex to pinia, however some problems arose. The store inside my component is set up correctly as, when debugging, i see that i receive the wanted object and correct data and with set breakpoints that individual functions work correctly.
Specifically  `<v-card-title>{{ userDetails.name.givenName + ' ' + userDetails.name.familyName }}</v-card-title>` here i get an error that _ctx.userDetails.name is undefined which implies to me that at that time the object isn't "there" yet.
My question then would be why userDetails seems to be undefined at that point although it has been properly introduced by these map-functions? Or maybe i have a misconception about something. I'd be happy about some help.

As the "getUserDetails" function is async i tried to put a "v-if=userDetails.name" to stop it from erroring as i have seen in another thread but to no avail. Inside "computed" i have the user object, but as i already have the mapActions in place i changed every "user." to "userDetails". - no change.

[_ctx.userDetails.name is undefined but the object exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9DGv.png)

Comment: "i tried to put a "v-if=userDetails.name" - not shown in the question. It's unknown why it's "no avail", it works in simple and predictable way and should work as intended. It's unclear why you didn't have problems with vuex, data flow would be exactly the same. It's also not shown where the component calls getUserDetails

Comment: You are right, i accidentally put the methods of the component into the store of this snippet, "getUserDetails" is being called in "beforeMount"

Comment: There's a typo in `"v-if`, make sure you don't have it. This is expected to work but this depends on how vuetify works which also needs to be verified, v-if may not work if a comp extracts the content of a slot, which could be the case. Any way, since you use a router, you don't have to create race condition where you could avoid this. Make sure you fetch all necessary data in router hook

Comment: strange. Do you have a minimally reproducible example that based on what you provide it must work

Comment: @EstusFlask i see, i'll try to look into that, thanks

Comment: @TachibanaShin i'll try to set one up

Comment: @EstusFlask vuetify does not have access to `v-if` it is compile!

Comment: @TachibanaShin Can you clarify? I mean that if a comp processes slot content like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000029/3731501 , which is common, v-if won't be applied. Cannot verify if this is the case for vcard

Comment: @TachibanaShin so i tried but i am afraid i cant do it because i believe it is necessary that i have the "async geUserDetails" to make it reproducible. 
However, i tried by putting v-if's at some other places where "userDetails" was used and it seemed to render at last. Its not viable for production though and just shifts the problem to a later date i am afraid.

Comment: So a temporary fix is to catch this "missing" promise of the "async getuserDetails" with a v-if so it does not stop on an error but'll need a better, more stable solution i think.