# How to create a custom select component with options passed as HTML instead of props in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to create a custom select component that can accept options as HTML like this:

```
<MySelect v-model='value'>
  <MyOption value='1'>Option 1</MyOption>
  <MyOption value='2'>Option 2</MyOption>
</MySelect>
```

This is my current implementation of the custom select component:

```
<template>
    <div class="select">
        <div class="text" @click="visible=!visible">{{modelValue ?? text}} <IconChevronDown/></div>
        <div class="options" v-if="visible">
            <span v-for="option in options" class="p-4 hover:bg-neutral-1 cursor-pointer capitalize" @click="select(option)">{{option}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const visible = ref(false)
const props = defineProps({
    text: String,
    options: Array,
    modelValue: String
})
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"])

function select(option){
    visible.value = false;
    emit("update:modelValue", option)
}
</script>
```

This component accepts options as a prop and just as an array of strings. But I need more customization of options, such as adding an icon or applying styles to text. So, the ability to pass options as HTML would have solved this problem. I would appreciate if you could share your ideas of how this can be implemented!

P.S. MySelect component should not contain native select and option tags. The whole purpose of creating a custom select component is for design customization.

Comment: you haven't shown any code for `MySelect` nor `MyOption` components - so, at a guess, you either did something wrong, or didn't do a thing

Comment: what code am I supposed to show? I am asking how to implement this because I couldn't myself. I have my version of MySelect, but it accepts options as a prop. Do you want it?

Comment: Well, as Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's probably better that you show that you at least attempted to solve your "problem" - that's how this place is supposed to work

Comment: I have added my version of the component. Have a look.

Comment: If you want to use your `<MyOption` components, you'll need a [slot](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html)

Comment: I don't have any idea of how to implement it with slots. If you have one inner tag, yes, you could use slots. But you have arbitrary number of options here. How would you do that? And it is also not just a dropdown, where you display contents. You need to handle click event to each option and get their value.

Comment: Even if you, say, handle click event inside MyOption component, how would you pass its value back to MySelect?

Comment: Are you sure you have to use that syntax? Why not use the array passed in as `:data=...~` for `MyOption`

Comment: Your idea is basically doable but why do it?

Comment: How does it relate to the question asked? It doesn't solve anything.

Comment: With options passed as prop, you cannot style them separately. This is the main point of passing options as an HTML

Comment: You definitely have to convert them into html like that, then how do you render them? In the end, you still have to use `v-for` like you would pass an array

Comment: This needs to be implemented with render function, it's more flexible. MySelect receives MyOption vnodes through a slot and can read myOptionVnode.props and myOptionVnode.children (it's not a slot until it's rendered), like https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000029/3731501 . The comment above regarding :data has a point, it would do the same thing if data structure is right. You won't gain anything from  "html" except it looks neater (it's not real html, these are vnodes, there's no style at that point)

Comment: Maybe you don't understand vue, if you think that passing an array cannot be passed by a custom component, then that's wrong.

Comment: I will implement your idea even though I really don't know what you are trying to do

Comment: @EstusFlask I will take a look into the render function. But why do you say passing options as html doesn't solve the problem. This will give you a control over styling each option separately.

Comment: @JohnBaker It's just another way to pass data to a component, you can process data object in a way you need. Could be like `:data="[{ content: ..., props: ...}]` to not treat style, class, etc props in a special way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom slot render function and collect default slots of the slotted child components:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Usually I would prefer the scoped slot solution posted in my other answer here, BUT nobody stops from MERGING 2 solutions into 1: using the default slot from here and `#option` from the other answer. So the select component could be fed by both slots.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MySelect from './MySelect.vue';
import MyOption from './MyOption.vue';

const selected = ref();
</script>

<template>
  <my-select v-model="selected">
    <my-option value="1"><span style="color:red">Red option</span></my-option>
    <my-option value="2"><span style="color:blue">Blue option</span></my-option>
  </my-select>
</template>
```

MySelect.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="select">
        <div class="text" @click="visible=!visible" style="cursor:pointer">
            <component v-if="modelValue" :is="options[modelValue]"/>
            <template v-else>{{ text }}</template>
        </div>
        <div class="options" v-if="visible">
            <render-options></render-options>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref, useSlots} from 'vue';
const visible = ref(false)
const props = defineProps({
    text: {type: String, default: 'Toggle dropdown'},
    options: Array,
    modelValue: String
})
const options = ref({});
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"])

const $slots = useSlots();
const renderOptions = () => {
    options.value = {};
    return $slots.default()
    .map(vnode => {
        // collection options' default slot
        options.value[vnode.props.value] = vnode.children.default;
        Object.assign(vnode.props ??= {}, {onClick: () => select(vnode.props.value)}, vnode.props ?? {});
        return vnode;
    });
}

function select(option){
    visible.value = false;
    emit("update:modelValue", option)
}
</script>
```

MyOption.vue

```
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
  <div class="option">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.option{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I didn't know you can use variables as a component, but will look into it. Huge thanks!

Comment: @JohnBaker here's the docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function

Answer (score 1):

Customizing list items is usually done with scoped slots:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MySelect from './MySelect.vue';

const options = [{id: "1", title: 'Option 1'}, {id: "2", title: 'Option 2'}];
const selected = ref();
</script>

<template>
  <my-select :options #option="{id, title, select}" v-model="selected">
    <div class="option" @click="select">id: {{ id }}, title: {{ title }}</div>
  </my-select>
</template>

<style scoped>
.option{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

MySelect.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="select">
        <div class="text" @click="visible=!visible" style="cursor:pointer">{{modelValue ? options.find(o => o.id === modelValue).title : text}}</div>
        <div class="options" v-if="visible">
            <template v-for="option in options">
              <slot name="option" v-bind="{...option, select: () => select(option.id)}">
                <span class="p-4 hover:bg-neutral-1 cursor-pointer capitalize" @click="select(option.id)">{{option.title}}</span>
              </slot>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';
const visible = ref(false)
const props = defineProps({
    text: {type: String, default: 'Toggle dropdown'},
    options: Array,
    modelValue: String
})
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"])

function select(option){
    visible.value = false;
    emit("update:modelValue", option)
}
</script>
```

You can also automatically handle the selection click, but for that you need a custom render option slot component. Plus of cause you can use your own component to pass to the slot:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MySelect from './MySelect.vue';
import MyOption from './MyOption.vue';

const options = [{id: "1", title: 'Option 1'}, {id: "2", title: 'Option 2'}];
const selected = ref();
</script>

<template>
  <my-select :options #option="{id, title}" v-model="selected">
    <my-option :value="id">{{ title }}</my-option>
  </my-select>
</template>
```

MySelect.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="select">
        <div class="text" @click="visible=!visible" style="cursor:pointer">{{modelValue ? options.find(o => o.id === modelValue).title : text}}</div>
        <div class="options" v-if="visible">
            <template v-for="option in options">
              <render-option v-if="$slots.option" v-bind="option" @click="select(option.id)"/>
              <span v-else class="p-4 hover:bg-neutral-1 cursor-pointer capitalize" @click="select(option.id)">{{option.title}}</span>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref, useSlots, mergeProps} from 'vue';
const visible = ref(false)
const props = defineProps({
    text: {type: String, default: 'Toggle dropdown'},
    options: Array,
    modelValue: String
})
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"])

const $slots = useSlots();
const renderOption = props => $slots.option(props)
    .map(vnode => (Object.assign(vnode.props ??= {}, {onClick: () => select(props.id)}, vnode.props ?? {}), vnode));

function select(option){

    visible.value = false;
    emit("update:modelValue", option)
}
</script>
```

MyOption.vue

```
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
  <div class="option">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.option{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this is not quite the desired result. Here, you are creating options array in parent component, and then passing it to MySelect to obtain that data back in option for styling. It does provide solution to some degree. But I don't think this is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: @JohnBaker that's a recommended way by Vue documentation to handle customization of list items. btw, I haven't finished my answer yet, your solution comes the last 

Comment: @JohnBaker added a "probably more" clean solution

Comment: yes, it does look cleaner. But do you know how to implement it in a similar way to this: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select. Look at the section where it says "manually provide your options". Because, that is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Especially if you have three or four options, it would make more sense.

Comment: @JohnBaker added your desired solution as a separate answer