VUE Passing slot from child component to parent
I'm trying to create a Table component with filtering
This is how I want to use it
<v-table :data="users">
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.full_name')" field="full_name" />
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.image')" field="image" align="center" />
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.phone')" field="phone">
        <template #body="slotProps"><v-input v-model="slotProps.data.phone" /></template>
        <template #filter="slotProps"
            ><v-badge>{{ slotProps.data.full_name }}</v-badge></template
        >
    </v-table-column>
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.email')" field="email" />
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.ip_address')" field="ip_address" align="center" />
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.city')" field="city_id" />
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.language')" field="language_id" />
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.active')" field="active" align="center" sortable />
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.created_at')" field="created_at" sortable />
    <v-table-column :label="t('users.updated_at')" field="updated_at" sortable />
</v-table>

Here is my component VTableColumn which injects column data to build a table
<script setup>
import { defineProps, onMounted, inject, useSlots } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
    label: String,
    field: String,
    align: String,
    sortable: Boolean,
})

const slots = useSlots()

const columns = inject('columns')

onMounted(() => {
    columns.value.push(props)
})
</script>

Here is the table component itself VTable
<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref, useSlots, computed, provide } from 'vue'
import { Filter, Trash, Pencil, ChevronDown, ChevronUp, RefreshCcw, Columns } from 'lucide-vue-next'
import useTable from './composables/table'

const slots = useSlots()

const props = defineProps({
    data: Object,
})

const columns = ref([])

provide('columns', columns)

const getColumns = computed(() => {
    return columns.value
})

const { thClasses, tdClasses } = useTable()

const onSortChange = () => {}
</script>

<template>
    <slot />

    <div class="relative overflow-x-auto bg-white rounded-xl">
        <table class="w-full text-sm text-gray-500">
            <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700">
                <tr>
                    <th v-for="column iyn getColumns" :key="column.field" scope="col" class="px-6 py-3" :class="thClasses(column)">
                        <template v-if="column.sortable">
                            <div @click="onSortChange(column)" class="text-sky-500 flex items-center gap-x-2 cursor-pointer">
                                <span>{{ column.label }}</span>
                                <span>
                                    <ChevronDown class="text-sky-500 w-4 h-4" />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        <template v-else>{{ column.label }}</template>
                        <slot name="filter"></slot>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(row, index) in data.data" :key="index" class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-50">
                    <td v-for="column in getColumns" :key="column.field" class="px-6 py-4" :class="tdClasses(column)">
                        {{ row[column.field] }}
                        <slot name="body"></slot>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

I was able to transfer column props to the parent VTable component using inject provide, but I don’t understand how to give me slots (Body, Filter), slot body VTableColumn must replace the td column values in the table, slot Filter should appear after th.

It's usually not implemented this way. You could only read the props from v-table-column and never really render it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000029/3731501
